# Example of a group action G on a vector space V that fails to be linear (i.e. fails to be a linear representation).

Tags: representation-theory, examples-counterexamples, group-actions

I have seen the following definition of a linear group representation from C. Lent's [notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/~teleman/math/RepThry.pdf) on Representation Theory:

> A **linear representation** $ρ$ of $G$ on a complex vector space $V$ is a set-theoretic
>   action on $V$ which preserves the linear structure, that is:
>
> 1. $ρ(g)(v_1 + v_2) = ρ(g)v_1 + ρ(g)v_2, ∀v_1,v_2 ∈ V$
> 2. $ρ(g)(kv) = k · ρ(g)v, ∀k ∈ C, v ∈ V$

This definition would imply that there exist actions of $G$ on a vector space $V$ which fail the preserve the linear structure of $V$ in this sense.  Can anyone provide a good example?

Comment: What would such a "non-linear" representation preserve, if not sums and scalar products (really the only two features of a vector space)? I think the name just suggests what kind of objects we're acting on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more thinking I have thought of an example:

Consider the translation action of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group under additon on $\mathbb{R^2}$ given by:  $n * (x,y) = (x+n, y)$.

We can verify that this does indeed form a group action:

1. $m * (n * (x,y)) = m * (x + n, y) = (x + n + m, y) = (m+n) * (x,y)$
2. $0 * (x,y) = (x + 0, y) = (x,y)$

However, this action does not respect scalar multiplication for $k \neq 0$ and $n \neq 0$ since this gives $n * (k(x,y)) = n * (kx, ky) = (kx + n, ky) \neq (kx + kn, ky) = k(x+n, y) = k (n * (x,y))$.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember rightly, a standard sort of example would be: take the space of matrices
$$ A(k)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & k \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, $$
for real $k$. This is a group under multiplication with $A(k)A(-m) = A(k-m)$. Define an action of $\rho$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$ \rho(A(k))(v) = v+k $$
for any $v \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, this is an action since
$$\rho(A(k))(\rho(A(m))(v)) = (v+m)+k = v+(k+m) = \rho(A(k)A(m))(v) \quad \text{and} \quad \rho(A(0))(v)=v,$$
but
$$ \rho(A(k))(u+v) = u+v+k \neq u+k+v+k = \rho(A(k))(u)+\rho(A(k))(v), $$
and
$$ \rho(A(k))(\lambda v) = \lambda v+k \neq \lambda(v+k) = \lambda \rho(A(k))(v), $$
so none of the linear structure remains.

Comment: I just read your answer after finding an example myself.  Upon further inspection, my example feels very much related to yours:  We can consider identify the integers $\mathbb(Z)$ as a subgroup of the space of matrices $A(k)$ by the isomorphism $n \rightarrow A(n)$.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I dressed mine up to look like matrices, but yes, at the end of the day, you can't get much simpler than $\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\mathbb{R}$. :)

Answer (score 1):

An important example coming from representation theory is the so called "dot" action of a Weyl group for a semisimple Lie algebra acting on the dual Cartan.  It is given by the formula $w \cdot \lambda = w(\lambda+\rho)-\rho$ where the non-dot action is a linear one, so it can be thought of as a shifted linear action where we have moved the origin to $-\rho$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples:

- The most extreme example is the **symmetric group** on the underlying set of $V$.
- The **affine group** of $V$, which is generated by invertible linear maps and translations. This can be generalized by replacing ${\rm GL}(V)$ with any matrix subgroup $G$ to get $V\rtimes G$. In particular $G=1$ gives us the group $V$ acting on itself by translations.
- Considering $\Bbb R^n$ as a real $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, consider

  - The **isometry group** of invertible distance-preserving maps.
  - The **conformal automorphism group** of invertible angle-preserving maps.
  - The **diffeomorphism group** of self-diffeomorphisms.
  - The **homeomorphism group** of self-homeomorphisms.

We can check these all act nonlinearly in one go: each action is transitive, hence there are group elements that send the origin to nonzero vectors.

The answers of Chappers, Nate and GoatsRule all fall under the second bullet point.