# What are the orbits of tensor product under the action of a product of groups?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions

Suppose that group $G_i$ acts on finite dimensional complex vector space $V_i$ with finite number of orbits for $i=1,2$. Let $G=G_1\times G_2, V=V_1\otimes_{\mathbb C} V_2$ and let $G$ act on $V$ by $(g_1,g_2).v_1\otimes v_2=(g_1v_1)\otimes (g_2v_2)$. [**Edit:** Here a $G$ action on $V$ means a linear representation.] Is there a general way to describe the orbits of the group action of $G$ on $V$ in terms of the orbits of the $G_i$ action on $V_i$? (**Edit:** if it is easier, one can assume the representation $V_i$ of $G_i$ is irreducible.)

If the above question has no general answer, here is a more concrete one. Suppose that $G_1=GL_2(\mathbb C)$ and $V_1=\mathbb C^2$. Suppose that $G_2$ acts on a complex vector space $V_2$ with 4 orbits $0, C_1,C_2,C_3$, then is there a way to describe the orbits of the natural $G_1\times G_2$ action on $V_1\otimes_{\mathbb C}V_2 $ in terms of $C_1,C_2,C_3$?

The following are some efforts I tried for the concrete example. The space $V_1\otimes V_2$ can be interpreted as $Hom_{\mathbb C}(V_1^*,V_2)\cong M_{2\times n}(\mathbb C)$, where $n=dim V_2$. The action of $G_1\times G_2$ on $Hom(V_1^*,V_2)$ is given by $(g_1,g_2).f=g_2fg_1^{-1}.$ We can consider the ranks of $f$. If $rk(f)=0,$ there is only one orbit. If $rk(f)=1$, there are 3 orbits depending on the image of $f$. But I don't know what happened if $rk(f)=2$. I am very confused about the last case. I am wondering if there is a general method to solve this kind problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that the action of $G_1\times G_2$ on $V_1\otimes V_2$ is well defined?

Comment: @OliverJones Yes. It is assumed to be well-defined.

Comment: What do you mean "assumed"? It either is well-defined or there are conditions on the action that make it well-defined. Which is it?

Comment: @OliverJones "Assumed" means that the problem itself assume the action is well-defined. You can explore the condition which makes the action well-defined if you like. I think that is what ``assumed" means in every math problem.

Comment: You're approaching this problem in the wrong way. Start with the definition of the tensor product of two vector spaces, verify that the induced action is well-defined, and then look at the orbit of a general element.

Comment: @OliverJones The tensor product representation of $G_1 \times G_2$ from representations of $G_1$ and $G_2$ is a standard construction in representation theory. Why are querying it? But I am not sure whether you can enumerate the orbits of its action just from a knowledge of the numbers of the orbits of $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Comment: For the case of $V_1 \cong V_2 \cong \mathbb C^n$ and $G_1 \cong G_2 \cong GL_n(\mathbb C)$, you get orbits $O_0, \dots, O_n$, where $O_k$ is exactly all the matrices of rank $k$.

Comment: @Calle I understand this case. But I am wondering what would happen if one of $V_i$ is not the standard representation of $GL_n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your comment. I am wondering if it is known for the special case, i.e., when $V_1=\mathbb{C}^2$ is the standard representation of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $V_2$ is some representation of $G_2$ with a small number of orbits (but a little bit more complicated than the standard representation of another $GL_n$).

Comment: @DerekHolt The OP makes no mention of representation theory. He just talks about a group acting on a vector space.

Comment: @OliverJones I understand that my approach is wrong and that is why I asked this question here. I apologize for any confusion caused by the wrong original wording/phrase of the problem   I really appreciate if you can point out a correct approach. I am sorry that I am too dumb to see how your comment " then look at the orbit of a general element" would help to solve this problem. By the way, for me, "group action on a complex vector space" and "representation of a group on a complex vector space" are the same.

Comment: @QingZhang Group actions coincide with linear representations only when the group acts linearly on $V$. Your question relates to the external tensor product of two representations and I don't think that there is a general decomposition result concerning orbits. Consider a simple case where $V_1=V_2=\Bbb{C}^2$ and $G_1=G_2=\Bbb{C}^*$. Calculate $\Bbb{C}\otimes \Bbb{C}$ from the definition (don't use $Hom(\Bbb{C}, \Bbb{C})$). Then compute the orbit of a general element to see if there's any description in terms of the orbits in $\Bbb{C}^2$.

Comment: @OliverJones I probably misunderstood your example here. At one point, you said $V_1=V_2=\mathbb{C}^2$, and the you wrote calculate $\mathbb{C}\otimes \mathbb{C}$.  As I explained in one comment, I understand how to compute the orbits when both $G_i$ actions on $V_i$ are the standard representations. The result is indeed  replies on the fact that the standard representation only has 2 orbits, 0 and nonzero vectors. As I said, I probably misunderstood your question.

Comment: @QingZhang Sorry, that's a typo. I meant $\Bbb{C}^2\otimes \Bbb{C}^2$. I'm not sure what you mean by standard representations.

Comment: @OliverJones According Wikipedia, a linear representation is just a representation on a vector space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation I think at the beginning, I said let $G_i$ act on a complex vector space $V_i$, which is exactly a linear representation according Wikipedia. But again, I don't know if the usage is standard or not. Thanks again for your comment to make this question more readable.

Comment: @QingZhang $G$ can act on $V$ as a set. Without the condition that it acts linearly, it won't be a representation. Here's a link that explains what I mean: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445825/55622

Comment: @OliverJones Standard representation means the natural (it is ambiguous, but it is really the natural) action of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ (matrix multiplication on column vectors). Again, I am sorry for the usage of non-standard terminology.  Now I see your example. However, in your example, the action of $G_i=GL_1(\mathbb C)$ on $V_i=\mathbb C^2$ has infinite number of orbits, which is not the case I want to address here. It is supposed to be more complicate than the finite number orbits case.

Comment: @OliverJones Now I see your point. Thanks again. I think I did not pay much attention to the difference of the terminologies when I was in college.

Comment: @QingZhang The number of orbits is irrelevant. What complicates the description of an orbit is the action of $G_1\times G_2$ on the indecomposable vectors in $V_1\otimes V_2$.